# There exist two distinct elements of $G\setminus H$ which commute?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $(G, *)$ be a finite group of odd

Because $G$ has odd order, every element x frhas order greater than 2, so I think, the condition that H is non-commutative is just to confuse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take any element $g\neq 1$ of G\H. Since $G$ has odd order, this element has odd order. So $g$ generates a cyclic subgroup of odd order. Thus, $g^{2}\neq g$ and we get $g g^{2} = g^{2} g = g^{3}$.

Comment: Maybe an obvious question: $H$ need not be normal, so $xHyH=xyH$ might not hold. (The usual way to show the left side contained in the right uses $H$ normal...) Sorry if this is a simple question.

Comment: @coffeemath What is your question? It is true that $xHyH = xyH$ might not hold, but what has that got to do with the fact that $g$ and $g^2$ commute? You do need to prove that $g^2 \not\in H$, but that's not hard.

Comment: @DerekHolt I thought the commuting elements were to be in $G \backslash H$, the collection of cosets $gH$.

Comment: Did you write G\H in the question when you meant $G/H$? The former means the set of elements in G not in H. The latter is the set of cosets of $H$.

Comment: $G \setminus H$ means the set of elements of $G$ that do not lie in $H$.  You are mixing it up with $G/H$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks. I have seen the backslash notation used to denote the collection of cosets when they are not assumed to form a group, and in those texts the forward slash is used only when $H$ is a normal subgroup.

Comment: how to prove that $g^2$ is not in H?

Comment: If $g^{2}$ in $H$, then $g^{4}$ in H must be a distinct element. But $H$ is not commutative. Thus, this is a contradiction.

Comment: It may be simpler to work with $\{g,g^{-1} \}.$ Since $g$ has odd order (and $g$ is not the identity, as it lies outside $H$), $g^{-1} \neq g$ and $g^{-1} \not \in H$ as $g \not \in H.$ Certainly $g$ and $g^{-1}$ commute. Note that a dihedral group $G$ with $2n$ elements, where $n>1$ is odd, shows that the conclusion need not hold if the oddness of $|G|$ is not assumed, taking $H$ to be the unique subgroup of order $n.$

Comment: It's not necessary to assume that g is different from 1, because this follows from the fact that g is not in H (Each subgroup contains the identity element of the group). Thanks!

Comment: @neelp I read it carefully and I have now some questions (sorry for late response) 1.What do you mean with "distinct element"? Is that $g^2$ different from $g^4$? 2.Why must $g^4$ be a distinct element? 3.From whom follows that $g^2$ is different from g? 4.What is the role of the cyclic subgroup of odd order? I think, the proof should be written again. :-)

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Why is $g^{-1}$ different from g and $g^{-1}$ does not lie in H?

Comment: $g^{-1} = g$ would give $g^{2} = e.$ But $g \neq e$ and $G$ has odd order, so $G$ contains no element of order $2.$

Comment: If we had $g^{-1} \in H,$ then since $H$ is a subgroup, we would have $(g^{-1})^{-1} \in H.$ But $(g^{-1})^{-1`} = g$ and $g \not \in H.$